# Lua/LOVE2D - attempt to index local 'quad' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

The issue lies with line 26, because quad does not work here, but it does in other lua scripts.

I attempted to use this code in order to make a system to update animations for sprites akin to a class module.

The line on it's own is fine, but then when used in line 29 and 49, it then gives me an error.

I have checked for typing, used similar issues and answers to and no success. It's near line for line form a video by a guy named "recursor", and my code STILL refuses to cooperate.

```
local class = require("class")
local Anim = class:derive("Animation")
local Vector2 = require("Vector2")

function Anim:new(xoffset, yoffset, w , h, column_size, num_frames, fps, loop)
    self.fps = fps
    self.num_frames = num_frames
    self.column_size = column_size
    self.start_offset = Vector2(xoffset, yoffset)
    self.offset = Vector2()
    self.size = Vector2(w, h)
        --loop = false, playthrough once, otherwise, loop forever
    self.loop = loop == nil or loop
    self:reset()
end

function Anim:reset()
    self.timer = 1 / self.fps
    self.frame = 1
    self.done = false
    self.offset.x = self.start_offset.x
    self.offset.y = self.start_offset.y
end

function Anim:set(quad)
    quad:setViewport(self.offset.x, self.offset.y, self.size.x, self.size.y)
end

function Anim:update(dt, quad)
    if(self.num_frames <=1) then return

    elseif self.timer > 0 then
        self.timer = self.timer - dt
     if self.timer <= 0 then
            self.timer = 1/ self.fps
            self.frame = self.frame + 1
            if self.frame > self.num_frames then
                 if self.loop then
                    self.frame = 1
            else
            self.frame = self.num_frames
            self.timer = 0
            self.done = true
             end
            end
            self.offset.x = self.start_offset.x + (self.size.x * ((self.frame - 1) % (self.column_size )))
            self.offset.y = self.start_offset.y + (self.size.y * math.floor((self.frame - 1) / self.column_size))
        -- print (self.frame .. ""..self.offset.x .. "  " .. self.offset.y)
            self:set(quad)
         end
    end
end


return Anim
```

Comment: Why is your `quad` separate from the animation class? here is a tutorial as an example: https://love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Animation

Comment: Issue was in main.lua ."hero_sprite" was in the incorrect update function (updated code)

```function love.load()
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest', 'nearest')
    hero_atlas = love.graphics.newImage("assets/gfx/hero.png")


    hero_sprite = love.graphics.newQuad(0, 30, 30, 30, hero_atlas:getDimensions()) 

   --self, puts selfvalue so function can operate
   --x,y,width,height, height, sw[ref width] ,sh [ref height])
end


function love.update(dt)  ---WAS here, incorrect
    if dt > 0.035 then return end

    a:update(dt, hero_sprite)  --NOW here, correct
```